# НЕ или всё-таки НИ?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

"*Странно, каких только путей мы не (или всё-таки НИ) выбираем, чтобы скрыть свои истинные чувства*".

Уверена, что НЕ, но какое правило здесь применимо?

Answer (score 3):

> Розенталь, Справочник по правописанию и стилистике, § 72 (5):
>
> В *независимых* восклицательных и вопросительных предложениях (часто со
> словами только, уж) пишется отрицательная частица **не**, а в *придаточных*
> предложениях (с уступительном оттенком значения) для усиления
> утвердительного смысла – частица **ни**.
>
> *Куда только он **не** обращался! (общий смысл: «обращался во многие места»). – Куда только он **ни** обращался, везде встречал равнодушное
> отношение.*
> http://www.textfighter.org/text1/38_naprimer_predlozheniyah_obraschalsya_4.php

В вашем случае оборот имеет место *не* в придаточном предложении, поэтому "**не**". По смыслу здесь восклицание, близкое к риторическому вопросу с простым отрицанием (скажите, каких ещё мы **не** выбирали путей?).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь - **"не"**. Розенталь (см. Alex_ander) - хорошо, но если непонятно, попробуйте рассмотреть "полную версию". ***Нет таких путей, которые мы не выбирали.***  Так яснее?

Одно могу добавить, ошибка частая, не всегда без контекста удается понять, уступительная это конструкция (с "ни") или усилительная с (с "не"). Но в данном случае все более или менее понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, **какие только пути мы не  выбираем**, чтобы скрыть свои истинные чувства.

Это, действительно, частица НЕ в риторическом вопросе (смысловое значение: сложно назвать те пути, которые не выбираем). Но здесь следует использовать **винительный падеж** (с родительным падежом риторический вопрос даже не сразу узнается).

[**Розенталь, §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

4) в вопросительных и восклицательных предложениях, общий смысл которых не имеет характера отрицания, например: **Куда только я не забрасывал свою вторую металлическую приманку**, вооруженную острыми колючками?! (Г. Федосеев);