# Ни один словарь не фиксирует слово "полезыш", что бы оно значило?

Tags: не-или-ни, окказионализмы, диалектизмы

[В чем меня только ни обвиняли. Дорого мне обошлась хвалебная рецензия Бухарина. «Бухаринское охвостье», «полезыш Троцкого»…](https://e-libra.ru/read/413856-zelenaya-lampa-sbornik.html)

Увидела дополнительный вопрос к тексту Либединской:

"В чем меня только **ни** обвиняли" - не восклицательное по форме и интонации. Почему всё же **ни**, а не **не**?

Comment: По поводу не-ни вот вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429945/%D0%9D%D0%95-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%9D%D0%98/429946. Смотрите ответ Александра. Здесь независимое предложение, значит, должно быть НЕ. Если всё же надо отстоять такое написание у автора чем-то, ну не знаю тогда...

Comment: Это не мой автор. Ошибку я увидела, прочитав мною приведённую цитату. Это - кинохроника с прожектором, сто редакторов с корректором... (с)

Answer (score 1):

У Даля есть слово ***"полаживать"*** в значении сделать что-то (полезное, надо понимать), мастерить, производить, исправлять, делать "ладным". Совершенный вид к нему - "полезть". 
"Полезыш" как производное к последнему в вашем контексте выглядит вполне органично.

Не очень понятно, как сие диалектное слово проникло в тот круг, но ведь не сказано, что его использование было массовым. Вполне мог разово употребить носитель такого диалекта - оно и запомнилось. Тем более что интуитивно оно понятно носителю русского. Ясно же, что он "польза", а не "ползти".

> "В чем меня только ни обвиняли" - не восклицательное по форме и
>   интонации. Почему всё же ни, а не не?

Ошибка. 
Причем оно как раз восклицательное по своей сути. Но это никак не спасает. Смысл тут "во всем обвиняли", нет ничего такого, в чем бы **НЕ** обвиняли. То есть НЕ очевидное при любой интонации и типе предложения.
Но тут такое дело... Текст был написан явно давно, чуть ли не век назад (по стилю). А тогда с этими НЕ и НИ разбирались несколько по другому. Как именно - не скажу, но точно было очень много отличий от современных более или менее упорядоченных правил.